# Create a type that converts a typed array to its first element

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there any reason why in Typescript I can't create a generic type that converts its typed array to the type of its first element? See example:

```js
export type Single<T = any[]> = T[0];
//                              ^^^^
// Type '0' cannot be used to index type 'T'
```

kinda like if you were to use an index on an array?

```js
export const obj: Single<MyObject[]> = arr[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the definition is that your parameter `T` defaults to `any[]`, but can still be set to a non-array value. You need to use the `extends` keyword to make sure that `T` is limited to array types:

```
type Single<T extends any[]> = T[0];
```

See also: [TypeScript Handboook - Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints)

Note that you can add back the `= any[]` portion to allow you to use the `Single` type without explicitly specifying the generic.

```
type Single<T extends any[] = any[]> = T[0];
type NumberSingle = Single<number[]>; // number
type AnySingle = Single; // any
```